# merging video files in to split-screen

Tags: video, transcode

I'm taking in video with an online flash applet (such as tokbox, but yet undecided).  I need to combine multiple video streams in to one movie with up to four videos arranged together in a square.  Can I use transcode server-side?  Can I use a hosted service, like zencoder, to make life easier?

Answer (score 1):

You have several options for this:

- xuggler: offers the ability to do what you're asking in 'real-time'. You'll have to code this up as a java applet and use a resource like Red5 or similar to apply the filter. This could be used either on live streams or pre-recorded. http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/
- ffmpeg: there are several postings about combining videos that all seem to be working. You may have to convert your source .flv to something like .mp4 or .avi first. YMMV.

See:
[FFMPEG 2 Videos transcoded and side by side in 1 frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293265/ffmpeg-2-videos-transcoded-and-side-by-side-in-1-frame)
[Superimposing two videos onto a static image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390714/superimposing-two-videos-onto-a-static-image?lq=1)